# Load file string names into an array from Documents Directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I want to add a list of Files in Document Directory to an Array of Strings. Not sure exactly how to do this, this is what I have so far. I want to load/store only the files that contain the word 'bottom' in the filename in the array. How do i do this exactly?

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSFileManager *fileMan = [[NSFileManager alloc]init];
NSArray *files = [fileMan contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];

for(int i =0; i<files.count; i++){

}
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString rangeOfString:@"bottom"]];


//THIS IS HARDCODED ARRAY OF FILE-STRING NAMES
  NSArray *bottomArray =[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"bottom6D08B918-326D-41E1-8A47-B92F80EF07E5-1240-000005EB14009605.png", @"bottom837C95CF-85B2-456D-8197-326A637F3A5B-6021-0000340042C31C23.png", nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check each file in the `files` array:

```
NSFileManager *fileMan = [NSFileManager defaultFileManager];
NSArray *files = [fileMan contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];

NSMutableArray *bottomArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *file in files) {
    if ([file rangeOfString:@"bottom"].location != NSNotFound) {
        [bottomArray addObject:file];
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thank you, that works, but now i am trying to load an image from that string file name, and it was working with the hard coded code but now it doesn't work with this - it keeps saying breakpoint thread 1 , not really sure why this line of code below isnt working now.. any thoughts/suggestions/corrections ?                                              

        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[NSString stringWithFormat: [bottomArray objectAtIndex:i]]]];

Comment: That's because `i` isn't there in my answer. You already have `file`, use it to build the path.

Comment: i have no idea how to do that or what that means.. i just want bottomArray[i]

Comment: i want to have a loop that loads images from document directory one at a time... where i=0 until files.count then start all over again with i=0

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @rmaddy's approach, another option is to use an instance of `NSPredicate` to filter the array of file names:

```
NSArray *filenames = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:NULL];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self contains 'bottom'"];
NSArray *matchedNames = [filenames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```